# can we get the below result with col name col 1,col2,col3,col4 and in 1st row there is region name and in 2nd row there is sales value

Tags: sql

| Region | Sale |
| --- | --- |
| East | 4428019.20999999 |
| South | 2583410.82099996 |
| West | 4740244.4394999 |
| Central | 3289180.15899995 |

Can we transpose above table into below table ?

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | East | south | West |
| 2 | 4428019.20999999 | 2583410.82099996 | 4740244.4394999 |

can we get the result with two rows. 1st row with region and 2nd row with sales value with column namae as col1,col2,col3,col4

Comment: Despite superficial resemblances, SQL tables and Spreadsheets are different things. Notably, in spreadsheets rows and columns are largely interchangeable. In SQL tables, columns have a *fixed type* and should always contain only the same "logical type" of data in each row for that column. What you're asking for isn't an SQL result.

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL as well. I've removed the conflicting tags; please (re)tag the (R)DBMS are you are really using.

Comment: Is your structure fixed? Meaning, do you always want east, south and west values only? Or that part is also dynamic? If it is fixed, then something can be done

Comment: Add some more rows of sample data, and also specify the new result.

Comment: What happened to Central?

Comment: It's in the markdown, @jarlh . The problem is the OP only has 4 headers in their table, so the 5th column (with Central) isn't getting displayed in the markdown table.

Comment: @Larnu, those darn markdown tables...

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you ask but try simple transposition of rows to cols by PIVOT: (in Oracle it looks like)

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    your_table PIVOT( 
        MAX(sale) FOR region IN (
            'East' AS Col2
            , 'South' AS Col3
            , 'West' AS Col4
            , 'Central' AS Col5
        )
);
```

And if you still really need header row simply previously use second query with static values like:

```
SELECT 1 Col1, 'East' Col2, 'South' Col3, 'West' Col4, 'Central' Col5 FROM dual
UNION ALL
[...]
```